# Maven not finding apache RandomStringGenerator

Tags: java, apache, maven, apache-commons

I am trying to use the new Apache Commons Text new random string generator, but I can't find any usage on the Internet on how to properly import it. Maven builds successfully, but when I try to run my jar file from the command line with the following command

```
java -cp target/my-app-1.0.jar com.mycompany.app.App
```

…I get the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/text/RandomStringGenerator$Builder
        at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.text.RandomStringGenerator$Builder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

I also have this warning during the build:

```
The POM for org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more detail
```

Here is the Maven debug version:

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-text\1.1\commons-text-1.1.pom: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not a (position: START_DOCUMENT seen a... @1:1)  @ line 1, column 1
```

Here is my `App.java` code:

```
package com.mycompany.app;
import org.apache.commons.text.RandomStringGenerator;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Generates a 20 code point string, using only the letters a-z
        RandomStringGenerator generator = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
            .withinRange('a', 'z').build();
        String randomLetters = generator.generate(20);
        System.out.println( randomLetters );
    }
}
```

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run you application from a jar, you will need an exploded jar.  The default class loader will not find the apache jar from your jar.

You can use the shade plugin to create an exploded jar. Add something like below to your `pom.xml`:

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>com.mycompany.app.App</Main-Class>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Then, you can run with the following:

```
java -jar target/my-app-1.0.jar
```